# Get JSON to return list Book using while loop

Tags: php, json, while-loop

I want to create a list of books that I can return as a valid JSON output. There should only be one JSON output that outputs a list of books. I have this at the moment but the problem is only the last book of the while loop is added to the list Book which is what I want to return.

```
//Return each book found given search.  
while(list($book_id, $title, $authors, $description, $price) = mysqli_fetch_row($search)){  

$thisBook = array("book_id"=>$book_id,"title"=>$title,"authors"=>$authors,"description"=>$description,"price"=>$price);

$Book = array();
$Book[] = $thisBook;

}


//JSON Return
$success = TRUE;
$message = "Success";
$output = $Book;
echo json_encode($output);
```

How could I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Book = array();

while(list($book_id, $title, $authors, $description, $price) = mysqli_fetch_row($search)){  

$thisBook = array("book_id"=>$book_id,"title"=>$title,"authors"=>$authors,"description"=>$description,"price"=>$price);


$Book[] = $thisBook;

}
```

You were over-writting the array inside the loop so was getting the last data.
So declare `$Book = array();` outside the loop